# Android Studio 3.6 Canary 12 XML layout doesn't resolve

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, xml-layout

I have updated my Android studio to latest version and I am facing some issues.

- When I create a package and inside the package I create an empty activity, for some reason it doesn't recognise the R.layout.Name of XML layout.

I am not sure what is the issue or I might missed some adjustments? Any help or clue will be highly appreciated it.

I also attached the photo in case to clear my issue.**strong text**

Comment: I had to import R to my layout.!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Synching Gradle Online if you have set Gradle Offline mode.
Kindly attach some screenshot or log text so that the actual problem can be recognized.

Comment: Thanks Adnan, I fixed the issue. I was meant to import R to the activity.